# Parsing JSON Schema using Json.NET schema throws error System.MethodAccessException

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I am trying to experiment with JSON schema validation. I am using the basic example for the schema on the [JSON.NET Help page](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/JTokenIsValid.htm). I get the exception

```
System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method
'Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema.Parse(System.String)' to access method
'Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(System.Object, System.String)' failed
```

My code is below

```
[TestMethod]
    public void prettySimple()
    {
      string schemaJson = @"{
             'type': 'object',
             'properties': {
             'name': {'type':'string'},
             'hobbies': {
             'type': 'array',
             'items': {'type':'string'}
                }
               }
              }";

      JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson);
    }
```

Comment: Are you referencing `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema`?

Comment: Yes I am. Also referencing Newtonsoft.Json.Schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a package mismatch between Newtonsoft.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.

Newtonsoft.Json.Schema relies on Newtonsoft.Json version>= 6.0.8. So make sure it is up to date in your project.

I installed Newtonsoft.Json first and then the schema package and code ran fine for me.

My packages config:

```
 <packages>   
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />   
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net45"/> 
</packages>
```